# PHPdoc & XAMPP - classdiagram not generated

Tags: xampp, virtualhost, phpdoc

I am using PHPdocumentor on a project running on XAMPP.
I have ran PHPdoc and all the documentation is in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\documentation
```

I have a vhost-configuration for this in my httpd-vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@documentation.dev
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/documentation"
ServerName www.documentation.dev
ServerAlias *.documentation.dev
ErrorLog "logs/documentation.dev-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/documentation.dev-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And a line in drivers\etc\hosts:

```
    127.0.0.1       www.documentation.dev
```

**Issue**

The problem is the class-diagram called by a generated html that is positioned:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\documentation\classes.svg
```

When I go to the url www.documentation.nl/classes.svg I get an error 500 on the image.

I am using the latest versions of XAMPP an PHPdoc and the (only working) template: responsive-twig.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently PHPdocumentor isn't meant to work with a virtual host.
When I click on the index.html and run the entire site from a folder, everything works fine.